How long can I safely store soaked (but not cooked) *soy* beans in the fridge?
I make my own soy milk using a plant milk maker. The maker itself is very quick - it takes about 40 minutes to make a litre of soy milk. But soaking the soy beans takes hours, which means if I run out of milk before I expect to, I have to wait at least six hours for my next cup of tea!
I know with most beans, it is safe to store rehydrated beans in the fridge on a paper towel for several days. Is this also the case for soy beans? I'm wondering if it might be different for them because so many other things seem to be different for soy beans (such as the long cooking time). If I could soak them in advance, I could put a batch on to soak whenever I make a new bottle of soy milk, and always have rehydrated beans at the ready!

This question is similar to: How long can I store soaked beans before cooking?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
